# Android toolbar not doing what I want

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I have a nearly full screen dialog fragment in my app, containing a toolbar on top. I want to style this toolbar like in the [Material design guidelines](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/dialogs.html#dialogs-full-screen-dialogs):

[image: material dialog]

Toolbar XML:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:title="@string/new_folder"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    android:background="@color/primary_dark"/>
```

menu XML:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
  <item
    android:id="@+id/action_done"
    android:title="@string/action_save"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_done_white_48dp"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="always|withText" />
</menu>
```

In my Dialog Fragment, code relevant to the toolbar:

```
 private Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener mMenuItemListener = new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                dismiss();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_done:
                dismiss();
                return true;
        }
      return false;
    }
```

...

```
    mToolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_close_white_48dp);
    mToolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_folder);
    mToolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(mMenuItemListener);
```

My toolbar looks like this:

[image: toolbar troubles]

I have four problems:

1. The 'Save' text is not displayed next to the checkmark, even though there is ample room for it
2. The X icon is too large (maybe use the 36dip version?)
3. The X icon is not clickable
4. The toolbar does not display the title ('New Folder')

What am I doing wrong?

Note that my toolbar is not set as the action bar! It's just a toolbar in a fragment.

Comment: 3. Use         mToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(mNavigationItemListener);

Comment: 4. Use mToolbar.setTitle(R.string.new_folder);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I don't think that you should but texts in the menu side (right of the toolbar). Looking at the guidelines, you can see that is not a good practice, and all the examples show menus only with icons
2. From the guidelines, I think you should use 24dp (http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/icons.html#icons-system-icons in the section 'Clearance')
3. Use

   toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener();
4. you need to set the title like

   toolbar.setTitle("'New Folder")

Comment: setNavigationOnClickListener also does not called.

Answer (score 2):

> The 'Save' text is not displayed next to the checkmark, even though
>   there is ample room for it

This is not possible. You can show only text or only icon.

> The X icon is too large (maybe use the 36dip version?)

You should use 24dp version.

> The toolbar does not display the title ('New Folder')

Because you are in Fragment so you need to set title explicitly into Toolbar and from you code i don't see source code that doing this. You need to do it programatically (via xml it seems it's broken) and i prefer to you use support library.

> The X icon is not clickable

You need to use `OnNavigationClickListener` and not `OnMenuClickListener`, your `X` icon is navigation icon not menu icon.